# dialogflow context vs. intent - Design Choice

Tags: dialogflow-es

I started working with Dialogflow a couple of weeks ago. It's nice to learn the concept of intent and (input/output) context through which Google models and defines the daily conversation flow in natural language. I understand how intent and context work at the current setting. But to me the function of context can be achieved by only using intent. You may argue whether the word 'intent' is proper for this usage but it's another discussion. So instead of input and output context just do input and output intents. In the implementation make sure the parameters and information of current conversation is carried to the following intent. And the following intent has again its output intent and the talk continues.

Can anyone correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Intents represent a user action, typically what a user says, including the parameters from that specific utterance.

Contexts serves two purposes:

- Hold the parameters from an Intent or that have been set through Fulfillment for some period of time.
- When used as an Input Context, limit what Intents can be triggered.

While you can certainly "send the parameters forward" from one Intent to another, this is a very linear way of thinking, and rapidly falls apart in complicated conversations. Using Contexts to store parameters and other info, as the first bullet suggests, makes this a lot easier, so your user can wander around in the conversation, and yet you are still maintaining the overall state.

As for the second bullet, this is used to change how we understand what the user has said based on other parts of our conversation. (This matches how humans handle conversations.)

So my response saying "Yes" means different things depending if I'm asking to delete a message or send a message - Contexts help us manage that.

Comment: my thoughts exactly!!

Comment: A bit more to write here: I was working on some intent and its input/output contexts others have built. Some context names were the same as that of intents and at first I thought these output context bar is to be filled with intent names.  When I found out later that they are just contexts I came up with this question.  To me it could be designed in a way without the term/concept of context. Just let all these functions of context be integrated in Intent e.g. holding parameters, passing info to the next and etc.Do you have any example of complex conversation to give me more understanding?